# Gate и Policy Laravel

Tags: php, gate, policy

Мне нужно запретить другим пользователям редактировать посты. Чтобы только тот пользователь который создал пост, мог его редактировать

**Я попробовал через Policy**

Код `PostPolicy`

```
    public function update(User $user, Post $post)
    {
        return $user->id === $post->user_id;
    }
```

В `AuthServiceProvider` добавил в $policies `Post::class => PostPolicy::class,`

И в контролере редактирования

```
    public function __invoke(User $user, Post $post)
    {
        $this->authorize('update', $post);
        return view('main.post.edit');
    }
```

Мой Route

```
Route::get('/{post}/edit', 'EditController')->name('main.post.edit');
```

Моя БД

```
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->id();
            $table->string('username');

        Schema::create('post', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->id();
            $table->string('user_id');
            $table->string('title');
```

Делал по докоментации и всеравно не пускает.

**Потом я решил сделать через Gate**

В `AuthServiceProvider`

```
        Gate::define('post-edit', function (User $user, Post $post){
           return $user->id === $post->user_id;
        });
```

И в контролере редактирования

```
    public function __invoke(User $user, Post $post)
    {
        if (! Gate::allows('post-edit', $post)) {
            abort(403);
        }
        return view('main.post.edit');
    }
```

Так-же делал все по докоментации

Уже не знаю что делать...

Comment: почему `user_id` объявлен как стринг???? должен быть как `unsignedBigInteger` потому что `$table->id()` в таблице users возвращает bigint тип. И при строгом сравнении `===` типы у переменных не совпадают

Comment: @DmitriiSedov Спасибо за помощь)